# validate jqgrid data on the server, callback function

Tags: jqgrid

I am using autocomplete in a textbox on my jqgrid. But i should not allow the user to select the same item twice. Because of pagination he wont see all data all times. Is there a way that on sending new row to server check for duplicate data in the server and send a status back to jqgrid maybe poping up an alert sayign "row already exist on table". What would be the bst approach to do this validation and notify the user? thanks.

```
$("#assessmentproduct").jqGrid({
            url: 'orthofixServices.asmx/GetProductList',
            colNames: ['id', 'Product Description', 'Commission Rate'],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'id', hidden: true },
            { name: 'description', index: 'desc', width: 320, editable: true },
            { name: 'commissionrate', index: 'com', width: 120, editable: true, unformat: percentUnFormatter, formatter: percentFormatter, editrules: { number: true} }
            ],
            serializeRowData: function(data) {

                var params = new Object();
                params.id = 0;
                params.prdid = $("#prdid").val();
                params.description = data.description;
                params.commissionrate = data.commissionrate;
                var result = JSON.stringify({ 'passformvalue': params, 'oper': data.oper, 'id': data.id });
                return result;
            },
            mtype: "POST",
            rowNum: 4,
            height: 93,
            width: 400,
            pager: '#assessmentpager',
            editurl: "orthofixServices.asmx/ModifyProductList"
        });
        $("#assessmentproduct").jqGrid('navGrid', '#assessmentpager', { add: false, edit: false, del: true, refresh: false, search: false }, {}, {}, { serializeDelData: function(postData) {
            return JSON.stringify({ 'passformvalue': null, 'oper': postData.oper, 'id': postData.id });
        }
        });
        $("#assessmentproduct").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#assessmentpager', { addParams: { position: "last", addRowParams: {
            "errorfunc": duplicateRow, "aftersavefunc": function() { var grid = $("#assessmentproduct"); reloadgrid(grid); }
        }
        }, editParams: { "aftersavefunc": function() { var grid = $("#assessmentproduct"); reloadgrid(grid); } }
        });
```

Comment: I entered the new code as it stands on my file now. I only moved the afterfunc to the addRowParmas place..thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should just hold the simple rule: if an error occur on the server (for example because of validation error) the server response should contains some [error HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4). In the case error message will be displayed to the user.

The exact error processing and the displayed error message format depends from the editing mode which you use. In case of inline editing I would recommend you to use `errorfunc` and `restoreAfterError`  parameters of the [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow) method. In case of form editing the [errorTextFormat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) callback can be very helpful.

Comment: I could handle the error in the server; However, once the error is displayed the grid is invalid. It is useless I can not do anything else with it...how can i handle this?

Comment: I have posted my code. the server returns 2 so that i know there was a specific failure...

Comment: @ManuelValle: Which HTTP status code returns the server in case of error? In case of *successtul* status code the `aftersavefunc` callback will be called. The `errorfunc` will be called *only in case of some error HTTP status code*. What is your current problem? In the code I see that you use `errorfunc` callback `duplicateRow` *only for row editing*, but not in case of add new row or delete row.

Comment: The problem is that after the server returns Internal Server Error 500 the grid is useless, nothing works on it, the Add button is disabled and trying to hit any other button throws javascript exception, rowid not found...

Comment: @ManuelValle: You should debug to see what is the body of the HTML response in the case and what the method `errorfunc` do with the HTML.

Comment: The error is being handled in the server so the response is just {d: "2"} which i assigned at the server. but because the grid was trying to add a new row and it failed (because it was a duplicate item) then now the grid is not recovering gracefullly from that state and the add button stuck at disabled state and cancel will fire a javascript error because it can not find the rowid...How can i recover from that state?

Comment: @ManuelValle: Sorry, but probably you don't know the difference between the HTTP header which included the status code and the body (like `{d: "2"}`). See [here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) for example. About no error handling in "New" and "Delete" operations in your code I wrote you in previous comments before. For Add operation for example you have to define `addParams.addRowParams.errorfunc`. I recommend you to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for catching HTTP traffic.

Comment: I moved the errorfunc definition to the addRowParams section and it is never called when the error happens....

Comment: @ManuelValle: To be able to help you I need see the current code which you use.

Comment: I moved the afterfuc ot the addRowsParams place...I changed the code above